# Looking for a way to store a table (or any other type) of data on the server that never expires

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm not sure how to do the this. But I need to store data into two columns on the server, where column 1 has a static id and column 2 has a dynamic id that will change each time a client connects to the website.

The reason for this is to keep track of the dynamic id.

What should I look for exactly? I don't even know why my query on Google should be, and what is the best way of doing this, if possible at all.

Comment: the nature of storing data in a SQL database is that the data does never expires.  But this seems a bit too easy of a answer to your question. are you familiar with databases at all?  if not that may be the basis of your question.  Alternatively, you could write an XML file to the server so the data persists outside of the session.  Depending on resources you have; may indicate what direction to go.

Comment: Yeah I'm very familiar with SQL but I need something way faster, I guess XML could work.

Comment: by faster I assume you mean easier / quicker to setup... because reading/writing to a database is DARN fast, industry standards.  This sounds like a quick/dirty app that needs to be done.  Cookies could be used; but I don't like them personally... if .net there is an application session which could be used but if IIS crashes or app server restarts you lose the persistance...   Honestly the BEST long term is database storage, the 2nd best for quick and dirty, imo is XML to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard to implement.  You can use an RDBMS to store the persistent data.  I'm not sure if you already have one, but I'd recommend SQL Server.

Have a table like this:

```
create table UserId
(
    UserIdStatic int identity(1, 1) not null, -- or whatever you want to use for a static id
    UserIdDynamic int not null
)
go
```

Then you can create a function to get a random number that isn't already taken in your `UserId` table.  This would work:

```
create view RandomNumGen
as
    select cast(rand() * 1000000 as int) as RandomNumber
go

create function RandUniqueId ()
returns int
as
begin
    declare @randomNumber int

    while (1 = 1)
    begin
        select @randomNumber = RandomNumber
        from RandomNumGen
        if not exists
        (
            select *
            from UserId
            where UserIdDynamic = @randomNumber
        )
        begin
            return @randomNumber
        end
        else
        begin
            continue
        end
    end

    return @randomNumber
end
```

*(Note: you need to create the view because you can't call `RAND()` in a UDF)*

Then when your user logs in, just generate a new random number and set it as their dynamic ID.

Comment: thanks, but suppose I have a large amount of users connecting each second. Is this the best approach?

Comment: @user1027620 This is how I'd do it.  Is it the best approach?  I think so.  This is a drop in the bucket, and very little load for a capable RDBMS (i.e. SQL Server).